# Moved Opencart site now product links not working

Tags: opencart

Basically duplicated http://www.smoothprint.co.uk at http://www.comitservices.co.uk/ben/ocart, I imported the old database into the new one and edited the php.ini files so they aren't both connected to the same database

However now the SEO friendly links aren't working and i'm not sure how to rectify this. Any ideas?

Comment: have you uploaded the .htaccess file ?

Comment: Yeah do I have to edit that in anyway?

Comment: It is the same .htaccess from the old site

Comment: your seo links does not work in what way? Do you get a 404, get redirected to another page? Please explain this.

Comment: Sorry should have said, it displays a error page

Comment: The FTP setting in system has the old url could this be the problem?

Comment: Nevermind the setting isnt enabled anyway so shouldn't be affecting it

Comment: make sure its exactly `.htaccess` and not `htaccess.txt` or somethng else. connection with db is fine which can be seen by accessing without seo url like http://comitservices.co.uk/ben/ocart/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have edited your `.htaccess` file's `RewriteBase` value. On your original store, it will have been

```
RewriteBase /
```

and for the new store it should be

```
RewriteBase /ben/ocart/
```

Although usually just removing the line completely will allow the file to work with both of those stores

Comment: Thanks alot! Thought it must of been something to do with .htaccess as its the only file you have to modify for SEO friendly urls to work